# How can I simulate a student-t copula in R based on marginals?

Tags: r, simulation, copula

I'm trying to simulate the joint distribution of Brent oil prices and an exchange rate to compare it to the empirical distribution. For this, I have been following this article: https://datascienceplus.com/modelling-dependence-with-copulas/

Based on the modeling I have done, I should employ a skewed Student-t marginal for the exchange rate, and a Student-t marginal for the Brent. However, I face two problems:

1. When modeling, I see the simulated data falls far away in terms of scale from what returns 
   should look like. You can see this comparing the empirical vs the simulated distributions in the picture below: 
   [image]
   [image]
2. I don't know if I'm estimating the DF parameter properly so this may affect the overall fit.
3. I don't know how to introduce the skewed-t as a marginal to be more precise with my 
   modeling.

This is the code I've used so far:

First I estimate the copula parameters based on the data:

```
copula_param <- fitCopula(ellipCopula("t", dim = 2), data = returns)

rho <- coef(copula_param)[[1]]
df <- coef(copula_param)[[2]]
```

Then I estimate the DF parameters for the marginal student-t distributions:

```
brent_df <- fit.st(returns[,1])$par.ests[[1]]
currency_df <- fit.st(returns_df[,2])$par.ests[[1]]
```

Finally, I use the `mvdc` and the `rmvdc` functions from the `copula` package to generate the simulations:

```
copula_dist <- mvdc(copula = tCopula(rho, dim = 2, df=df), margins = c('t', 't'),
                    paramMargins = list(list(df=brent_df), list(df=currency_df)))
joint_dist_sim <- rMvdc(4955, copula_dist)
```